# Customising graphs in R

Tags: r, graph, charts

1. I have the following piece of code for a graph:
   `barplot(as.vector(t(mat1[1,3:ncol(mat1)])),las=2)`
   that I would like to alter so that the *x*-axis is replaced by the line *y* = 2; effectively moving the *x*-axis up 2 units as in the image below.
   [image]

   I need the bars to begin at 2 so that:

   - a bar with a value of 3 begins from the y=2 line and **ascends** to end at y=3.
   - a bar with a value of 0 begins from the y=2 line and **descends** to end at y=0
2. How can I make the column names of `mat1` my *x*-axis categories?

Comment: To change the x-axis labels to the column names of `mat1`, use the `names.arg` argument in `barplot` (such as `names.arg=colnames(mat1)[3:ncol(mat1)]`). As to your first question, `barplot` usually doesn't plot the x axis when `horiz=FALSE`, which is the default. Do you want to plot the x axis, or do you want the bars of the bar plot to start at 2 instead of 0?

Comment: @BenBarnes I want the bars to begin at 2 and to ascend or descend to their value, i.e. the barplot is centered around y=2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Barplot always starts its bars at 0. Subtract 2 (or 5 as I did) from every y-value. Set ylim to range(y-values - 5). You will need to suppress plotting the y axis with yaxt="n". The xpd parameter to axis allows the range of labels to extend below the range of actual values.

```
 set.seed(231)
 tN <- table(Ni <- stats::rpois(100, lambda=5))
 tNshift <- tN-5
 barplot(tNshift, space = 1.5, yaxt="n", xaxt="n", ylim=range(tNshift))
 abline(0,0)
 axis(2, at= c(-5, pretty(tNshift)), labels=c(0, pretty(tNshift)+5), xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here is the first example from `?barplot`, slightly modified, with `abline(x,y)` added

```
require(grDevices) # for colours
tN <- table(Ni <- stats::rpois(100, lambda=5))

barplot(tN, space = 1.5, axisnames=FALSE)
abline(5,0)
```

[image]

Sorry if this is not answering your specific questing, but I did not have any sample data to work from so I took the `?barplot` example.

Comment: Nearly. The bars below y=5 are wrong; they should start from y=5 and go down to ~3 for the first two, etc.

Comment: @user1202664, Again, it's quite hard for me when I don't have some sample data to understand exactly what you are looking for. The placement of the bars have to do the the structure of the data. Try `barplot((tN-7), space = 1.5, axisnames=FALSE)` to see what I mean by _the structure of the data_.